# Return an object from google drive api function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, google-drive-api

I am still very green when it comes to NodeJS and the way Async/Await/Promises work, so please be patient and compassionate as you look through my explanation and my code sample.
I am trying to create modules in the form of functions to manage different parts of a project which will request data using the Google Drive API and push it to MongoDB collections that will be used to keep track of the different operations like uploads, downloads, etc. I already have this somewhat working by writing  the results from the functions to JSON files and parsing them but that's not efficient. I want to return an object from the function calling the Google API to list drives, file, etc. which I could then send directly to the MongoDB collection.
Here's an example of my function to list drives, notice I can log the results and write them to JSON but can't return the actual object with the data.
Your help is very appreciated and I welcome any guidance you can offer.

```
// Import Google library and token for account
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const credentials = require('./Creds/token.json')
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email, null,
    credentials.private_key, scopes
)
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth })

// List all drives
async function listDrives() {
    const alldrives = await drive.drives.list({
        fields: '*',
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        const drives = res.data.drives
        let results = []
        if (drives.length) {
            drives.forEach((file) => {
                results.push(file)
            })
        } else {
            results.push('No drives found in user account.')
        }
        //console.log(results) // <---- getting this in the console
        //results // <---- not getting this
        const fs = require('fs')
        fs.writeFileSync('./driveslist.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)) // Results to json file works
    })
    return alldrives
}
let drivestouse = listDrives()
    .then(data => {
        data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
drivestouse
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the actual object with the data`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected value?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, the response from the google drive for this method returns a json with the drives associated with the account. Here’s an example of what the structure should look like:  `{id: 'blahblah', name: 'blahblah', colorRgb: '#ff5722', kind: 'drive#drive'}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please confirm the version of googleapis for Node.js you are using. I tested my proposed script using `googleapis@100.0.0`. In the current stage, it seems that `googleapis@100.0.0` is the latest version.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
// List all drives
async function listDrives() {
    const alldrives = await drive.drives.list({
        fields: '*',
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        const drives = res.data.drives
        let results = []
        if (drives.length) {
            drives.forEach((file) => {
                results.push(file)
            })
        } else {
            results.push('No drives found in user account.')
        }
        //console.log(results) // <---- getting this in the console
        //results // <---- not getting this
        const fs = require('fs')
        fs.writeFileSync('./driveslist.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)) // Results to json file works
    })
    return alldrives
}
let drivestouse = listDrives()
    .then(data => {
        data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
drivestouse
```

#### To:

```js
// List all drives
function listDrives(drive) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    drive.drives.list(
      { fields: "drives(id,name,colorRgb,kind)" },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err.errors);
          return;
        }
        resolve(res.data.drives);
      }
    );
  });
}

listDrives()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

- When this modified script is run, the following result is obtained with `console.log(data)`.

  ```
    [
      { kind: 'drive#drive', id: '###', name: '###', colorRgb: '###' },
      ,
      ,
      ,
    ]
  ```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to get values from the shared Drive. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list)
- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: Thank you so much Tanaike, I'll mark this question as answered, however, when invoking the function the 'drive' parameter was missing. I'll add the change below for anyone looking for this answer to get the actual working code. Thanks for the detailed and prompt response.

Comment: @Robinsper Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When I tested the script, I used `drive` like that. By this, I forgot to modify it. I apologize for this. In your script, by `const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth })` as the global variable, I think that you can also modify `function listDrives(drive) {` to `function listDrives() {`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final solution that worked for this question, courtesy of @Tanaike. I just wanted to clarify by including the whole code block and by adding the parameter to the part where the function is invoked:

```
// Import Google library and token for account
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const credentials = require('./Creds/token.json')
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email, null,
    credentials.private_key, scopes
)
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth })

// List all drives
function listDrives(drive) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        drive.drives.list(
            { fields: "drives(id,name,colorRgb,kind, createdTime)" }, // <=== Add '*' to get all properties
            (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err.errors)
                    return
                }
                resolve(res.data.drives)
            }
        )
    })
}

listDrives(drive) // <=== It was missing this parameter
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```